# wrong special symbols matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

As it is my first post on SO, I would like to say "Hello everyone".

I have a problem using matplotlib. When I'm writing mathematical expressions all of special symbols like `r'$\bigodot$'` or `r'$\sigma$'` I recive completly different symbols. Here's a more specific example right from my code:

```
for i in radi:
    plt.plot(temp,Lum(i,temp),'--b')
    plt.text(temp[0],Lum(i,temp[0]),'R = '+str(i)+r'$R_\odot$')
```

and here's what I receive on plot:

[image]

I use python 2.7 on ubuntu 16.10. I would be grateful if you have any ideas on what I can do. Same code on my friends computers works fine.

Comment: Since the code probably produces the expected result on almost every system, I guess you would want to give a little more insight into what makes your system different. Which version of matplotlib are you using, on which backend, which fontset are you using, etc?

Comment: `Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep 17 2016, 12:08:02) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160914] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.get_backend()
u'TkAgg'`

About fonts... I didn't customized anything. I tried use : `plt.rc('font', family='STIXGeneral')` as it was suggested somwhere, but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using different fontsets?  `plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] =  "dejavusans"` with 'dejavusans' (default),  'dejavuserif', 'cm' , 'stix',  'stixsans' ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank You. When I used "dejavusans" i recived an error: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cw3.py", line 43, in <module>
    plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = u"dejavusans"
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 890, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError("Key %s: %s" % (key, str(ve)))
ValueError: Key mathtext.fontset: Unrecognized fontset string "dejavusans": valid strings are [u'custom', u'stix', u'cm', u'stixsans']
`

But with "stixsans" it works well. Thank You one more time:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib provides different fontsets to be used when rendering [MathText](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html). It may well be that the settings in your matplotlib installation do not fit and that you need to use a different fontset.

```
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "dejavusans"
```

Valid fontsets should be `'dejavusans'` (default in matplotlib 2.0), `'dejavuserif'`, `'cm'` , `'stix'` and `'stixsans'`.